# How to find a correct php file to edit in large live running web system?

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect, filesystems

I have a huge live running web site wich has lot of issues. This has developed by lot of programmers around the world. So If I want to fix some errors its really hard to find where it is and so on....These files are in zend framework. There are 100s of php files, css files java sripts files, etc. Is there any way that I can do global search a file or how to understand the file linkage of this kind of large systems?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Linux there are a bunch of ways to find the correct file -

**On the command line**

Find a file by name -

```
find . -name filename
```

Or the faster find a file by name -

```
sudo updatedb #Only needed the first time you run locate
locate filename
```

Search a directory's contents recursively for a string -

```
grep -ri somestring .
```

Here's a new trick I learnt recently - Using Ack! If you are on a Debian/Ubuntu system you can install ack by doing -

```
sudo apt-get install ack-grep
```

Then you can do -

```
ack-grep somestring
```

This is blazing fast!

**In IDEs**

In most IDEs or advanced editors you should be able to simply control click or right click and select "go to definition" to navigate to a function's definition.

I can attest that this works in Netbeans, Eclipse, Komodo, Emacs etc.

If you are open to adopting a new IDE, I suggest Netbeans. It's PHP mode is full of goodies including improved navigation. For example, to quickly open a file you can simply do Alt-Shift-O and type the filename.

Comment: if you're using locate you don't need to `updatedb` each time. That would make things incredibly slow!

Comment: @james-c, yes of course! I have updated my post to specify that.

Comment: Also, in Netbeans, you can <ctrl>-click on a function name or a member name and it will find it for you. Very helpful for tracing code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you'll need to learn a bit about Zend Framework, how it's MVC framework works and where the models, views and controllers are stored. This'll help you guess where to go looking for problems.

In terms of searching for specific lines of code or patterns most operating systems or IDEs will allow you perform a recursive search of a set of files. I think that's outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using aptana you can search your whole workspace by going to search->search. If you are using dreamweaver you can open find menu and search through your current site

Answer (score 0):

It will be pretty hard to locate the right file in a quick way if you don't have any knowledge about the application at all. I would recommend reading up on Zend Framework and how it's working.

[debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) can come in handy if you need to show a backtrace. This can be useful if you need to know from where a function has been called.

If you're searching for a file that outputs something, a simple "search all directories, recursive" search will probably do just fine. Most IDEs (even "simple" one like Notepad++) or even OSes have this built in.

Comment: Thank for your reply, If I have 100s of folders and wanna find a specific function name or field name what would be the best way? I use Notepad++ for editing and FileZila to FTP

Comment: Do you know the actual function name?

Comment: Actually the latest case I know the field name its writes to Database, I wanna find where its writes ? which php file and which function ?